# How can i access gateway user information in micro-services?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, microservices, jhipster

I have two modules - Gateway and Micro-services, generated using jhipster. Both using different databases. All the user and permission entities are in the gateway database, while the components generated and used by these users are in the micro-services database tables (Each of these tables have a column created_by_id which stores the user_id of the gateway user table by which the component is created).

**Requirement**
I have an api, which requires a list of all the components and its corresponding user information in a single `ResponseEntity`.

**Proposed Solution**
To achieve this, i need to access the gateway user table information in micro-services.

**Question**
How can i access a table from a different database in micro-services?